# My passport will expire during my trip. Should I renew it before I go?

Tags: passports, us-citizens

I am planning to go overseas (Ethiopia) next year and I already have a current passport.  I would like to stay longer than what my passport is good for.   Would I be able to renew my passport at the American Embassy in Ethiopia and stay in the country, or do I have to come back to the States, renew the passport and return overseas??

Comment: If possible you should renew before you leave. It can take _much_ longer for a passport renewal overseas. And, most countries will not admit you if your passport is about to expire.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can get your passport renewed from overseas i.e. from [Ethiopian U.S. Embassy](http://ethiopia.usembassy.gov/service/passport-applications.html). This link will provide you [list](http://photos.state.gov/libraries/ethiopia/956093/PDF%20Files/Passport%20Renewal%20for%20Adult%2018%20yrs%20old%20and%20above.pdf) of documents required for this process.

But if you know it is going to expire sooner, then you should get it renewed before your travel, and same has been advised by US Embassy, and as per [US Travel State guidelines](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/FAQs.html).

> Some countries require that your passport be valid at least six months
>   beyond the dates of your trip. Some airlines will not allow you to
>   board if this requirement is not met.  Consider the following
>   scenario: A country requires that you have at least six months of
>   validity on your passport. You currently have seven months of validity
>   on your passport.  However, your trip is two months from now. At that
>   point, you will only have five months of validity remaining on your
>   passport which is not enough to satisfy that country's entry
>   requirements. In this situation, you would need to renew your passport
>   before you can make your trip.

You can check validations for the country to which you are traveling from this [link](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country.html), which states that for **Ethiopia** your passport should have a six months validity and some other conditions are mentioned [here](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/ethiopia.html).

[image]